# How to handle the blamed situation?

Tags: software-industry, management, company-culture

I have been working in a corporate company for 1.5 years. I have given my good work, completing the tasks at the correct time. Since last month, I have been working in  project,with a Team Lead and a junior guy (who is not sufficient to complete the tasks on time). Yesterday because of the junior guy, the task got delayed and he went to home without even completing. So the Team leader puts a mail to the Project Manager(who blindly supports the team leader), that saying "No one is interested in doing the tasks or extend to work, so I have to complete the tasks on my own and it will take some time". This mail denotes both me and that junior guy. Today there will be an enquiry related to this and how can I handle this? 
I have worked with this team leader for 1 year and still he blamed me for this. How to face this kind of fake people and how to handle this situation?

Comment: He left early without completing his tasks, how about you? Did you stay to complete your tasks?

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative approach to blaming the junior person, consider concentrating on your own achievements and actions. Make a list of tasks you have completed on time. Make a list of incomplete tasks that you are willing to work on and estimate what you can get done when.

Comment: Weaker one will be very sad due to blaming him. Come on he is new. He may lose the job.

Comment: But he's not blaming the junior employee (JE), he's laying out his work and his willingness to take on more tasks if needed. There is nothing wrong with defending your work and your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the hierarchy of your team works - Is the direct report for both you and the junior guy the team lead? If so you are not responsible for the time he goes home and it is up to him to explain in the meeting why he left early and did not complete the work.

If the junior reports to you then you should not have let him go home without completing his tasks and it will be up to you to explain why you let him go without completing his tasks.

Either way, the team lead has failed to lead the team on this occasion - The finger has been pointed at the two of you and you'll both have the opportunity to explain yourselves. If his actions were indeed the sole cause of the failure then that will probably come out in the meeting and he will have to state his own case.

If I was the project manager I would be more concerned about how to get the work completed from its present point and I'd have very little respect for someone who shifted blame and failed to take responsibility for their actions.

I'd advise you to document where your time has been spent on this project so far and provide useful suggestions about how to get it back on track instead of stabbing the junior guy in the back.